# Changing QuickTime Conversion Default Settings for export

Tags: video, final-cut-pro

We recently just switched our production to anamorphic (SD) widescreen (720x486) and we're running into some issues getting our videos to export from Final Cut Pro (version 6) at the right size.

To get things looking correctly, our current workflow is to

- Go to Export->Using QuickTime Conversion.
- Then from there, leaving the "Use" dropdown on "Default Settings", we click [Options], then the [Size] button from the Movie Settings box and finally,
- Change the Dimensions dropdown from the current **Compressor native** (apparently the default setting, which has dimensions of 854x480) to **NTSC 720 x 486 16:9**.

See screenshot below:

[image: Settings to export the video at the correct size]

This is obviously a very tedious process to repeat for every video we want to export. Is there some way we can change the default settings (or something to that effect) so that it exports at that size as the default? While the Export Using QuickTime Conversion works well after you change that, if there's another simpler workaround, I'd likely be open to considering it!

Comment: Some suggestions here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2507322?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

Why not set your sequence settings in final cut to the desired resolution and aspect ratio before beginning a project? Then you will just have to select "export to QuickTime" without having to select all the options each time.